# Could we have a sideboard for tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

For example, would it be helpful if we had on the side, a list of tags that are synonymous with your question, so that people won't have trouble trying to remember or think-up the tags unnecessarily. Would this be a good idea?

Comment: Shouldn't this have the `feature-request` tag?

Comment: I swear, the Community auto-bump feature has it out for this question. Is there any way to make it stop?

Comment: @Marthaª If I recall it right, it doesn't ping it if there is an answer with a score of at least 1.

Answer (score 1):

On Stack Exchange, synonym tags are tags that are associated with another tag (the master tag); when a synonym tag is assigned to a question, it is replaced with the master tag.

If by "a list of tags that are synonymous with your question" you mean a list of tags that could be used for the question, I don't think that would be useful.
Looking at the tags already entered, it could be possible to list the tags that other questions used together them. For example, if I enter [article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article), I could get [the following list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles). (See the content of the "related tags" block in that page.)

- indefinite-article ×33
- grammar ×28
- definite-article ×26
- word-choice ×25
- grammaticality ×24
- grammatical-number ×9
- pronunciation ×8
- idioms ×7
- adjectives ×7
- differences ×6
- determiners ×6
- parentheses ×6
- acronyms ×6
- meaning ×5
- nouns ×5
- title ×3
- abbreviations ×3
- word-usage ×3
- names ×2
- etymology ×2
- phrases ×2
- modifiers ×2
- date ×2
- punctuation ×2
- possessive ×2

If I enter [article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article), and [indefinite-article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article), I could obtain [the following list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles+indefinite-article).

- word-choice ×14
- definite-article ×5
- grammaticality ×4
- pronunciation ×2
- abbreviations ×2
- grammar ×2
- acronyms ×2
- american-english
- possessive
- writing
- parentheses
- idioms
- adjectives
- nouns
- initialisms
- modifiers
- mathematics
- grammatical-number
- etymology

If I enter [article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article), [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), and [indefinite-article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article), I could obtain [the following list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles+indefinite-article+grammaticality).

- word-choice ×2
- abbreviations

Knowing the tags already used by other questions doesn't tell me which tags I should use.

Comment: I think he is not talking about synonym tags. He is asking if, while asking a question, we could have a list of tags - automatically generated by the website after analyzing the content of the question - on a side panel so that the person asking the question would not be so confused while thinking of which tags to enter in the "tags" field.

Comment: The OP said, "a list of tags that are synonymous" and on Stack Exchange sites _synonymous tags_ doesn't mean _related tags_. In any case, I expanded the answer in the case the OP mean a list of related tags.

Comment: I'm afraid that the tag system is hopelessly confusing as it currently stands; the multiple technical terms -- most of which are poorly or not at all understood by questioners (and occasional answerers) -- merely encourage people to pick at random, with no hope of using the tags to find anwers that are actually related, instead of merely containing the same strings. I would argue against expending any effort on creating a sidebar for tags, and instead discouraging their use.

Comment: @JohnLawler You are right: If users don't use the correct tags, having a sidebar for tags is useless, as it would list the wrong tags. I would hope the tags are correct in most of the cases, though. It is true that those wrong tags have more influence for tags that are used fewer times.